# PL/SQL SMTP: 501 Error: attribute value too long

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Se me está presentado un error al momento de crear un correo automático por la base de datos, estoy creando el body y me sale este mensaje de error:

> ORA-29279: error permanente de SMTP: 501 Error: attribute value too long
>
> ORA-06512: en "SYS.UTL_SMTP", línea 17
>
> ORA-06512: en "SYS.UTL_SMTP", línea 98
>
> ORA-06512: en "SYS.UTL_SMTP", línea 317
>
> ORA-06512: en línea 2

¿Cuál es el problema? ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo? Éste es mi código:

```
  inicioColTitulo               VARCHAR(3000) :='<td align="center"><font face="Arial" color="FFFFFF" size="2">';
  finColTitulo                  VARCHAR(3000) :='</font></td>';
  tituloTabla                   VARCHAR(3000) :='Vencimiento Importaciones Temporales a Corto Plazo';
  inicioCol                     VARCHAR(3000) :='<td bgcolor="#e9f3fc" align="center"><font face="Arial" color="#000000" size="1" style="vertical-align: bottom">';
  finCol                        VARCHAR(3000) :='</font></td>';

BEGIN

 OPEN nit_cursor 

    FOR select distinct(v.ID_CLIENTE)
          from V_CONTROL_22 v;

   LOOP FETCH nit_cursor

    INTO id_nit;
    EXIT WHEN nit_cursor%NOTFOUND;  

    mesg_body :=              '<html>';
    mesg_body := mesg_body ||   '<head>';
    mesg_body := mesg_body ||       '<title>Email</title>';
    mesg_body := mesg_body ||   '</head>';
    mesg_body := mesg_body ||   '<script>';
    mesg_body := mesg_body ||       'resizeTo(300,300);';
    mesg_body := mesg_body ||   '</script>';
    mesg_body := mesg_body ||   '<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" link="#000080">';

    SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') INTO mi_fecha FROM DUAL;
    mi_cadena := trim(            '<center>');
    mi_cadena := trim(mi_cadena ||  '<table border="0">');
    mi_cadena := trim(mi_cadena ||    '<tr>');
    mi_cadena := trim(mi_cadena ||      '<td>');
    mi_cadena := trim(mi_cadena ||        '<table border="1">');
    mi_cadena := trim(mi_cadena ||          '<tr bgcolor="000080">');
    mi_cadena := trim(mi_cadena ||            '<td colspan="10" align="center">');
    mi_cadena := trim(mi_cadena ||              '<b>');
    mi_cadena := trim(mi_cadena ||               '<font face="Arial" color="FFFFFF" size="3">');
    mi_cadena := trim(mi_cadena ||                 tituloTabla || '<br>');
    mi_cadena := trim(mi_cadena ||                 '*** Fecha Ejecución: ' || mi_fecha || ' *** ');
    mi_cadena := trim(mi_cadena ||               '</font>');
    mi_cadena := trim(mi_cadena ||              '</b>');
    mi_cadena := trim(mi_cadena ||             '</td>');
    mi_cadena := trim(mi_cadena ||            '</tr>');
    mi_cadena := trim(mi_cadena ||          '<tr bgcolor="000080">');
    mi_cadena := trim(mi_cadena || inicioColTitulo || 'Columna No. 1' || finColTitulo);
    mi_cadena := trim(mi_cadena || inicioColTitulo || 'Columna No. 1' || finColTitulo);
    mi_cadena := trim(mi_cadena || inicioColTitulo || 'Columna No. 1' || finColTitulo);
    mi_cadena := trim(mi_cadena || inicioColTitulo || 'Columna No. 1' || finColTitulo);
    mi_cadena := trim(mi_cadena || inicioColTitulo || 'Columna No. 1' || finColTitulo);
    mi_cadena := trim(mi_cadena || inicioColTitulo || 'Columna No. 1' || finColTitulo);
    mi_cadena := trim(mi_cadena || inicioColTitulo || 'Columna No. 1' || finColTitulo);
    mi_cadena := trim(mi_cadena || inicioColTitulo || 'Columna No. 1' || finColTitulo);
    mi_cadena := trim(mi_cadena || inicioColTitulo || 'Columna No. 1' || finColTitulo);
    mi_cadena := trim(mi_cadena || inicioColTitulo || 'Columna No. 1' || finColTitulo);     
    mi_cadena := trim(mi_cadena ||'</tr>');


    OPEN correo_cursor 
     FOR SELECT GCT.CA_CORREO_ELECTRONICO
         FROM GEN_CONTACTOS GCT
         WHERE GCT.ID_IDENTIFICACION = id_nit
         AND GCT.DO_CARGO_FUNCIONAL = 'RL'; 

     LOOP FETCH correo_cursor

         INTO emailCliente;
         EXIT WHEN correo_cursor%NOTFOUND;

         IF(correosCliente IS NULL) THEN

             correosCliente := emailCliente;

         ELSE

             correosCliente := correosCliente || ';' || emailCliente;

         END IF;

     END LOOP;

     CLOSE correo_cursor; 

     if (correosCliente IS NOT NULL) THEN

     conn:= utl_smtp.open_connection( EmailServer, Port );   
     utl_smtp.helo( conn, EmailServer );
     utl_smtp.mail( conn, 'marco@domino.com.co');            




     FOR otrosCorreos IN(SELECT AUS.CA_DIRECCION_CORREO empl
                           FROM ADM_USUARIOS AUS, GEN_FICHA_TECNICA GFTD
                         WHERE GFTD.ID_IDENTIFICACION_FUN = AUS.ID_IDENTIFICACION
                           AND GFTD.ID_CONSECUTIVO_FICHA = 22
                           AND SYSDATE BETWEEN GFTD.FE_INICIAL AND GFTD.FE_FINAL)

       LOOP

             utl_smtp.rcpt(conn,otrosCorreos.empl);

           IF(correosDir IS NULL) THEN

               correosDir := otrosCorreos.empl;

           ELSE

               correosDir := correosDir || ';' || otrosCorreos.empl;

           END IF;

       END LOOP; 


     correos := correosDir;

     mesg:= 'Date: '||TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'dd Mon yy hh24:mi:ss' )|| crlf ||
            'From: '||'marco@domino.com.co'|| crlf ||
            'Subject: Vencimiento Documentos' || crlf ||
            'To:   '||correos|| crlf ||
            '' || crlf ||mesg_body||'';

     utl_smtp.OPEN_DATA(conn);
     utl_smtp.WRITE_DATA(conn,'MIME-Version: 1.0' ||crlf||'Content-type: text/html' ||crlf||mesg);
     UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(conn,mi_cadena);

     FOR datos IN(SELECT NU_DO,
                         ID_CLIENTE,
                         NO_CLIENTE,
                         NO_PEDIDO,
                         NO_FAC,
                         MODALIDAD,
                         ACEPTACION_DIM,
                         FE_DIM,
                         FE_LEVANTE_INICIAL,
                         FE_VENCIMIENTO,
                         ID_DOCUMENTO_DO,
                         ID_DOCUMENTO_DEC
                    FROM V_CONTROL_22 V
                   WHERE V.ID_CLIENTE = id_nit )
     LOOP

      mi_cadena := trim('<tr bgcolor="#e9f3fc">');
      mi_cadena := trim(mi_cadena || inicioCol || datos.NU_DO              || finCol);
      mi_cadena := trim(mi_cadena || inicioCol || datos.ID_CLIENTE         || finCol);
      mi_cadena := trim(mi_cadena || inicioCol || datos.NO_CLIENTE         || finCol);
      mi_cadena := trim(mi_cadena || inicioCol || datos.NO_PEDIDO          || finCol);
      mi_cadena := trim(mi_cadena || inicioCol || datos.NO_FAC             || finCol);
      mi_cadena := trim(mi_cadena || inicioCol || datos.MODALIDAD          || finCol);
      mi_cadena := trim(mi_cadena || inicioCol || datos.ACEPTACION_DIM     || finCol);          
      mi_cadena := trim(mi_cadena || inicioCol || datos.FE_DIM             || finCol);
      mi_cadena := trim(mi_cadena || inicioCol || datos.FE_LEVANTE_INICIAL || finCol);            
      mi_cadena := trim(mi_cadena || inicioCol || datos.FE_VENCIMIENTO     || finCol);                      
      mi_cadena := trim(mi_cadena || '</tr>');                        
      UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(conn,mi_cadena);

     END LOOP;

     mi_cadena  := trim('</table></td></tr></table></center>');                       
     UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(conn,mi_cadena);

     mi_cadena := mi_cadena || trim( '<div style="font-family:verdana; text-align:justify;">'); 
     mi_cadena := mi_cadena || trim(     '<div>');
     mi_cadena := mi_cadena || trim(         '... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt nesciunt doloremque velit laboriosam laborum, earum labore odit reprehenderit temporibus hic totam quam, ad officia voluptates mollitia. At, officia minus expedita? ');
     mi_cadena := mi_cadena || trim(         '<ol>');
     mi_cadena := mi_cadena || trim(             '<li>');
     mi_cadena := mi_cadena || trim(                 ' Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt nesciunt doloremque velit laboriosam laborum, earum labore odit reprehenderit temporibus hic totam quam, ad officia voluptates mollitia. At, officia minus expedita? ');
     mi_cadena := mi_cadena || trim(             '</li>');
     mi_cadena := mi_cadena || trim(             '<li>');
     mi_cadena := mi_cadena || trim(                 ' Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt nesciunt doloremque velit laboriosam laborum, earum labore odit reprehenderit temporibus hic totam quam, ad officia voluptates mollitia. At, officia minus expedita? ');
     mi_cadena := mi_cadena || trim(             '</li>');
     mi_cadena := mi_cadena || trim(             '<li>');
     mi_cadena := mi_cadena || trim(                 ' Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt nesciunt doloremque velit laboriosam laborum, earum labore odit reprehenderit temporibus hic totam quam, ad officia voluptates mollitia. At, officia minus expedita? . ');
     mi_cadena := mi_cadena || trim(             '</li>');
     mi_cadena := mi_cadena || trim(         '</ol>');
     mi_cadena := mi_cadena || trim(         ' Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt nesciunt doloremque velit laboriosam laborum, earum labore odit reprehenderit temporibus hic totam quam, ad officia voluptates mollitia. At, officia minus expedita? ');
     mi_cadena := mi_cadena || trim(         '<ol type="a">');
     mi_cadena := mi_cadena || trim(             '<li>');
     mi_cadena := mi_cadena || trim(                 ' Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt nesciunt doloremque velit laboriosam laborum, earum labore odit reprehenderit temporibus hic totam quam, ad officia voluptates mollitia. At, officia minus expedita? ');
     mi_cadena := mi_cadena || trim(             '</li>');
     mi_cadena := mi_cadena || trim(             '<li>');
     mi_cadena := mi_cadena || trim(                 ' Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt nesciunt doloremque velit laboriosam laborum, earum labore odit reprehenderit temporibus hic totam quam, ad officia voluptates mollitia. At, officia minus expedita? ');
     mi_cadena := mi_cadena || trim(             '</li>');
     mi_cadena := mi_cadena || trim(             '<li>');
     mi_cadena := mi_cadena || trim(                 ' Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt nesciunt doloremque velit laboriosam laborum, earum labore odit reprehenderit temporibus hic totam quam, ad officia voluptates mollitia. At, officia minus expedita? ');
     mi_cadena := mi_cadena || trim(             '</li>');
     mi_cadena := mi_cadena || trim(             '<li>');
     mi_cadena := mi_cadena || trim(                 ' Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt nesciunt doloremque velit laboriosam laborum, earum labore odit reprehenderit temporibus hic totam quam, ad officia voluptates mollitia. At, officia minus expedita? ');
     mi_cadena := mi_cadena || trim(             '</li>');
     mi_cadena := mi_cadena || trim(             '<li>');
     mi_cadena := mi_cadena || trim(                 ' Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt nesciunt doloremque velit laboriosam laborum, earum labore odit reprehenderit temporibus hic totam quam, ad officia voluptates mollitia. At, officia minus expedita? ');
     mi_cadena := mi_cadena || trim(             '</li>');
     mi_cadena := mi_cadena || trim(         '</ol>');
     mi_cadena := mi_cadena || trim(         '<p><strong>loren loren 1</strong>  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt nesciunt doloremque velit laboriosam laborum, earum labore odit reprehenderit temporibus hic totam quam, ad officia voluptates mollitia. At, officia minus expedita? . </p>');
     mi_cadena := mi_cadena || trim(         '<p><strong>loren loren 1</strong>  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt nesciunt doloremque velit laboriosam laborum, earum labore odit reprehenderit temporibus hic totam quam, ad officia voluptates mollitia. At, officia minus expedita? ...');
     mi_cadena := mi_cadena || trim(         '</p>');
     mi_cadena := mi_cadena || trim(     '</div>');
     mi_cadena := mi_cadena || trim( '</div></body></html>');
     UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(conn,mi_cadena);      

     utl_smtp.CLOSE_DATA(conn);
     utl_smtp.quit(conn);
     correosDir:= NULL;
     correosCliente := NULL;
     mi_cadena := NULL;
     END IF;

 END LOOP;

 CLOSE nit_cursor;       

END pr_Consulta;
```

Comment: Me parece que algo en tu fila o codigo es demasiado largo.

Comment: Sería muy útil ver algo del código que produce este error con el fin de que los usuarios puedan replicarlo.

Comment: Necesitas agregar mas detalles para que te podamos ayudar.

Answer (score 1):

Tu servidor no soporta alguno de los atributos ya que es demasiado largo, usas `loops` para guardar datos en  `mi_cadena`, también noto que usas para datos multilínea:

```
UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(conn,mi_cadena);
```

Lo cual es correcto.

Pero recuerda que la restricción para **[UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA()](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/email-from-oracle-plsql#multiline)** es que **no debe ser mayor a 32K** (VARCHAR2).

El error 501 generalmente se produce por datos incorrectos ó malformados enviados al servidor.

Comment: Quizás podrías incorporar un **EXCEPTION** y ver que error te arroja la sentencia.

Comment: @Eduardo Munizaga mira ya lo intente y la exception es la siguiente: `Error:-29279
ORA-29279: error permanente de SMTP: 501 Error: attribute value too long` @Elenasys me suguieres que asigne una variable para cada tipo de dato, y porterior lo adicione?

Answer (score 1):

El Error 29279 corresponde a error en el envío y el 501 básicamente es de sintaxis:

> El comando fue correcto y reconocido, pero los parámetros (por
>   ejemplo, los argumentos de correo electrónico dirección) no son
>   válidos

Se puede deber a varias causas incluyendo algunas tan simples como no separar los mails con comas, a que el dominio de un email sea incorrecto,  no colocar los soportes de angulos `<nombre@dominio.com>` o alguna dirección de correo muy larga etc.

Sería interesante que hicieras la consulta a la DB limitando a solo un correo, que sepas que esta correcto, con el fin de descartar estas teorías e  irnos por otro lado.

Te dejo un documento donde aparecen todos los *SMTP Status Codes* , busca el 501 ya que aparecen varias posibilidades que deberás descartar: [ https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/44676047/Network__3-SMTP_Server_Status_Codes_and_SMTP_Error_Codes.pdf ] , Esperemos que esto ayude en algo.

Comment: ya tambien le agrege las etiquetas < y >, y tampoco funciono, por favor tener en cuenta que si comentareo la tabla que arma la vista funciona, o si comentareo el div con la informacion tambien funciona, pero si los dejo a los dos ahi es donde falla.

Answer (score 0):

Quizas debas revizar el tamaño que asignas a ese campo VARCHAR2. En caso de que el maximo no te sea suficiente y aun asi deseas guardar la cadena deberias guardar el texto como arreglo de bytes como BLOB o algun tipo de dato similar y despues capturar este y convertirlo a texto de nuevo. He realizado esto antes para almacenar estructuras XML leidas de un fichero .xml y me ha sido util guardarlo como arreglo de bytes con un tipo de dato BLOB.

Este es el tamaño en bytes que soporta BLOB:2,147,483,647 Bytes (2GB) si no se especifica un tamaño en la creacion de la columna

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, mira ya lo he intentado, es un Varchar2 de 32000, lo cambie a CLOB y me sigue generado el mismo error, cuando le realizo debug llego llego hasta `     utl_smtp.CLOSE_DATA(conn);
     utl_smtp.quit(conn)` y es cuando sale el error, comentareo la tabla y sin ningun problema envia el correo, igualmente cuando comentareo el bloque de texto e igualmente lo envia sin ningun problema